# Magento connect manager is disabled

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-connect

I am new to Magento and facing issue with Magento connect manager which is showing as disabled.
I am using free subdomain hosting and Magento

[image]

ver 1.9 is installed by hosting provider.
Please let me know how can I enable the same?

Thanks,